# How to incorporate images into my textured model

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

Another medical use case I need your help with!
I have a face scan with an image texture and I'd like to project content of another image on top without the need for manual texture painting.
This time it's a skin lesion that I want to incorporate in the textured scan of a healthy skin.
I've tried with the clone tool and with manual uv-editing but I'm not sure of the right approach. Could you please provide me with maybe a link to the right tutorial or a few words on how to achieve this aim?

Raw model:
[image]

Textured model:
[image]

Picture of skin lesion:
[image]

Awful representation of what I'm aiming for:
[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

**Edit**:
I tried incorporating the tips you gave me:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Some questions:
What affects the dark seam around the picture and how can I get rid of it?
How can I play with the colors and make the added image a bit darker?
Why did we create a new UV Wrap in the properties panel?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can mix the existing material with the image through a *(Color) MixRBG* in *Multiply* mode, make a second UV map for the spot itself if necessary, in that case use an *(Input) UV Map* node:

[image]

More details about the second UV map. Let's say that you use the already existing UV map for the base skin texture, here is what your material will look like, you'll have the *Texture Coordinate (UV* output) plugged into the *Image Texture*. For the spot, you'll need an *(Input) UV Map*:

[image]

To create a second UV map, go into the *Object Data panel > UV Map*, and click on the "+" button, keep this second UV map selected, select it in the *UV Map node*:

[image]

Then in your 3D view, in *Edit* mode, select the part where you want to see the spot, press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap and in the *UV Editor* place the UV over the skin spot (as you see I've painted white all around the spot so that the mix with your base color works fine):

[image]

Invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> in order to select the rest, unwrap and put the UVs over a white part of your image so that it won't be affected by any color:

[image]

Edit: From your last version, there is a problem with your second UV map, as you see some faces are over the spot part of your image while they should not:

[image]

To fix that, select the faces that you want the spot to appear, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to invert, then unwrap again, scale down and put the UV faces over a white part of your image:

[image]

Comment: Hello Moonboots. Thanks a lot for the advice. I incorporated the image texture as color1 and the spot as color2 but naturally can't define its position. Could you please briefly explain me how to add a UV map at the correct position? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello @fernweh73 I've edited my answer, please tell me if you understand

Comment: Hey @Moonboots thanks a lot! I tried your tips and edited my answer. could you have a look?  almost there :)

Comment: Could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? Use workupload for example

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Could you tell me how I can export the project as obj+ 1 combined file of textures?

Comment: You need to bake the diffuse onto one unique texture (you'll find some YT tutos on this topic), then export the object as wavefront (.obj), but for an obj you probably can't pack the image texture so I guess it needs to be in the same folder